# SABRE Passenger Details PNR without a PNR

Tags: xml, sabre

Sometimes, for some flights, SABRE is returning the response bellow when I try to make a book: EndTransactionLLSRQ: *IM AND CANCEL UNABLE SEGMENTS

What´s the right way to treat this error? In a right response, SABRE returns the PNR:

Comment: This sounds like a question that would be better asked of your account manager at Sabre, as the error suggests there is a business condition you need to handle, rather than a programming error that the general public would be able to help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When has the search been made you try to fulfill? Sounds like the status of the flights you try to book are not "HK" or "HL" but UC or so. This means you cant enter the pnr bc. the flight is not available in the predefined booking class.

Comment: You should clarify issues with the question in a comment before answering.

Comment: How can I check if the flight have an HK or HL status? In the document below  don´t have a property where I can filter by HL or HK flights. http://files.developer.sabre.com/doc/providerdoc/shopping/BargainFinderMaxRQ_v3-3-0_Design.xml

Comment: Hi Marcela - well you also posted the search documentation and not the booking one. Normally UC segements happen if there is some change in availabilitybetween search and time of booking. Depending on your flow if you use the orchestrated airbooking flow (EnhancedAirBookRQ) as a response FlightSegment  ... Status="HK". If its "UC" you cannot price it and can not end the transaction so it does not make sense to proceed to PassengerDetailsRQ

Comment: Thak you Thomas, that´s right. I saw in the document below that there are many others status: http://files.developer.sabre.com/doc/providerdoc/ServicesPlatform/EnhancedAirBookRQ_v3.8.0_Design.xml. According whith the SABRE document: "In order to successfully price an air itinerary the status code associated with the individual segments cannot be “NN,” “NO,” “UC," or ”US.”" The valid values for Status are: NN, HL, GK, QF, SA, MM, or OPEN. But, I didn´t find a dictionary in SABRE documentation that explain the meaning of each status.

Comment: Hk = holding Confirmed, hl = waitlisted, tk = timechange, uc = unable. That should be the most important. All stati can be found here = https://support.travelport.com/webhelp/uapi/Content/Air/Shared_Air_Topics/Air_Status_Codes.htm. Please note some are not used with sabre but those that are used are the same